# joomla add dynamic rows

Tags: joomla

I have a requirement in the joomla administrator panel.
I have a form when i click ADD ATTRIBUTE
I need to add a row also there should be delete option to deleted the row 
How can i do it .?

```
                              ADD ATTRIBUTE
element1 element2 element3       DELETE
element1 element2 element3       DELETE
element1 element2 element3       DELETE
element1 element2 element3       DELETE
```

Once all these are filled the user will click save
and it will save in the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to do this in a custom table, then I would use ChronoForms and ChronoConnectivity. This will allow you to create a custom form with a custom database table with the ability to add/edit/delete table rows.

[Tutorials here](http://greyhead.net/how-to-docs/chronoconnectivity)

[Downloads here](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like http://getk2.org/